# Understanding python's lstrip method on strings

Tags: python, string, methods

I ran into what I think is a bug, and I'm looking for confirmation or that I am not understanding how this method works.

Here's my basic output:

```
(Pdb) x = 'KEY_K'
(Pdb) x.lstrip('K')
'EY_K'
(Pdb) x.lstrip('KE')
'Y_K'
(Pdb) x.lstrip('KEY')
'_K'
(Pdb) x.lstrip('KEY_')
''
(Pdb) import sys
(Pdb) sys.version
'2.7.11 (default, Dec  5 2015, 14:44:47) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)]'
```

My understanding is that the final 'lstrip' in that example should have returned 'K', but it did not.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's right in the docs:

> lstrip(...)
>       S.lstrip([chars]) -> string or unicode
>
> Return a copy of the string S with leading whitespace removed.
>       If chars is given and not None, **remove characters in chars instead**.
>       If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping

`'K'` is in `'KEY_'`, that's why your last example returns `''`.

Note that `'K'` would not have been removed if preceded by a character that is not in `'KEY_'`:

```
>>> 'KEY_xK'.lstrip('KEY_')
'xK'
```

Answer (score 13):

The `lstrip()` function doesn't behave in exactly the way you think it might. `x.lstrip(argument)` removes any of the characters in `argument` from the left of the string `x` until it reaches a character not in `argument`.

So `'KEY_K'.lstrip('KEY_')` generates `''` because the last character, `K`, is in `KEY_`.

Comment: I feel like this is a great answer as well, but I can only pick one.

Comment: Ha, to be honest I think you made the right choice!

Answer (score 7):

The second arg of lstrip is the **set** of characters that will be removed. If you need to remove a substring, you may use:

```
if x.startswith('KEY_'):
    x = x.replace('KEY_', '', 1)
```