# Iterate through dictionary to replace leading zeros?

Tags: python

I want to iterate through this dictionary and find any 'id' that has a leading zero, like the one below, and replace it without the zero.  So 'id': '01001' would become 'id': '1001'

Here is how to get the data I'm working with:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)
```

so far I've been able to get one ID at a time, but not sure how to loop through to get all of the IDs:

My code so far: `counties['features'][0]['id']`

```
{ 'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'GEO_ID': '0500000US01001',
    'STATE': '01',
    'COUNTY': '001',
    'NAME': 'Autauga',
    'LSAD': 'County',
    'CENSUSAREA': 594.436},
   'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [[[-86.496774, 32.344437],
      [-86.717897, 32.402814],
      [-86.814912, 32.340803],
      [-86.890581, 32.502974],
      [-86.917595, 32.664169],
      [-86.71339, 32.661732],
      [-86.714219, 32.705694],
      [-86.413116, 32.707386],
      [-86.411172, 32.409937],
      [-86.496774, 32.344437]]]},
   'id': '01001'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: You have tagged it with pandas, is it a pandas question? If so please include the sample of dataframe.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok I added in how to get the data I'm working with

Comment: You will need to loop over the dict & use [lstrip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34544325/4985099) to strip the leading zero's ``for x in counties['features']: x['id'] = x['id'].lstrip('0')``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your dictionary **counties** has the following data. You can use the following code:

```
counties={'type': 'FeatureCollection', 
     'features': [ {'type': 'Feature','properties': {'GEO_ID': '0500000US01001','STATE': '01','COUNTY': '001','NAME': 'Autauga', 'LSAD': 'County','CENSUSAREA': 594.436},
    'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon','coordinates': [[[-86.496774, 32.344437],[-86.717897, 32.402814],[-86.814912, 32.340803],
      [-86.890581, 32.502974],
      [-86.917595, 32.664169],
      [-86.71339, 32.661732],
      [-86.714219, 32.705694],
      [-86.413116, 32.707386],
      [-86.411172, 32.409937],
      [-86.496774, 32.344437] ]] } ,'id': '01001'}, {'type': 'Feature','properties': {'GEO_ID': '0500000US01001','STATE': '01','COUNTY': '001','NAME': 'Autauga', 'LSAD': 'County','CENSUSAREA': 594.436},
    'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon','coordinates': [[[-86.496774, 32.344437],[-86.717897, 32.402814],[-86.814912, 32.340803],
      [-86.890581, 32.502974],
      [-86.917595, 32.664169],
      [-86.71339, 32.661732],
      [-86.714219, 32.705694],
      [-86.413116, 32.707386],
      [-86.411172, 32.409937],
      [-86.496774, 32.344437] ]] } ,'id': '000000000001001'} ]} 

for feature in counties['features']:
    feature ['id']=feature ['id'].lstrip("0")

print(counties)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)
```

Then iterate over the list if id's with your JSON structure. And update the id
as

`counties['features'][0]['id'] = counties['features'][0]['id'].lstrip("0")`
lstrip will remove leading zeroes from the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is shorter and faster way of doing this using json object hooks,

```
def stripZeroes(d):
    if 'id' in d:
        d['id'] = d['id'].lstrip('0')
        return d
    return d
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response, object_hook=stripZeroes)
```