# What is the correct way to use string.lstrip() in this failing example?

Tags: python-3.x, string, printing, format, strip

This code ...

```
print( "PO #{}".format('PUR-ORD-2021-00001'.lstrip('PUR-ORD-2021-')))
print( "PO #{}".format('PUR-ORD-2021-00002'.lstrip('PUR-ORD-2021-')))
print( "PO #{}".format('PUR-ORD-2021-00003'.lstrip('PUR-ORD-2021-')))
print( "PO #{}".format('PUR-ORD-2021-00008'.lstrip('PUR-ORD-2021-')))
print( "PO #{}".format('PUR-ORD-2021-00018'.lstrip('PUR-ORD-2021-')))
```

... returns:

```
PO #
PO #
PO #3
PO #8
PO #8
```

I'm no Python expert, but in my experience so far Python's results are always eminently sensible.  But this?  I can't make sense of it at all.

What's going on here?

---

Version:

```
me@mine:~$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: `lstrip` takes an iterable and strips each character of the iterable from the left. Since `'PUR-ORD-2021-'` is an iterable it strips every occurance of each character. (`'P'`, `'U'`, etc..) https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip

Comment: OOOH!  So it is stripping all 0s, 1s and 2s because of the 2021!  Got it!  Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem. It's a common mistake that leads to some nasty bugs.

Comment: I'd add it as an answer but it'll probably get marked as a dupe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544247/understanding-pythons-lstrip-method-on-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace part of the string to get the order number:

```
original_string = 'PUR-ORD-2021-00001'
order_number = original_string.replace('PUR-ORD-2021-', '')
print('PO #', order_number)
# PO # 00001
```

Comment: I ended up with -- print( "PO #{}".format('PUR-ORD-2021-00001'[13:18]))